# How to get app to be in landscape orientation in cocos2d 2.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, orientation, xcode4.3, uiinterfaceorientation

(Sorry I can't include the images.  I don't have a high enough rep so i just provided links to the images)

As the title says, I am having problems with my app in landscape mode.  I want the whole app to be in landscape mode so I selected only Landscape Left and Landscape Right in the Target Summary.  I also put this:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    }
```

in my AppDelegate.m.  I also went to my info.plist and put "Initial interface orientation to Landscape (left home button).  However my orientation in the simulator and on the actual device are wrong.  Here is a picture of what I have in my storyboard (what I want it to look like)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/iphoneimage2.png/

But this is what it looks like in my simulator and on my device

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/440/iphoneimage.png/

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** If you are running Cocos2d 2.0 rc1 or rc0a, then the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method should be placed in the RootViewController.m file. If you are running Cocos2d 2.0, the the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` should be placed in the AppDelegate.m file.

The method will already be in RootViewController.m if you used one of the templates in Cocos2d 2.0 rc1 or rc0a to create your app.

The method will already be in AppDelegate.m if you used Coco2d 2.0.

You just need to edit the method to only return the desired orientation you need.

Edit the method in your RootViewController.m or AppDelegate.m class, depending on which version of Cocos2d 2.0 you are using, to look like this to accommodate both landscape orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: I dont have a RootViewController.m  I have AppDelegate, IntroLayer, MainMenu (a subclass of UIViewController), CCViewController (for my cocos game), cocos2dViewController (a subclass of CCViewController), and GamePlay (which is where all the content for my game is).

Comment: If you made your app from one of the Cocos2d 2.0 templates that come with it, then you would have a RootViewController.m class. But if you do not have one, then whatever your main ViewController that your app is supposed to have would be the one to add that code to. In the AppDelegate, the apps main/primary view controller is the view controller that your glView is added to and that that same view controller is then added to the apps primary UIWindow.  It is possible that your AppDelegate is not setting up Cocos2d correctly to use a viewController, but Apple recommends that you do use one.

Comment: I did use a cocos2d 2.0 template for my app but it only started with AppDelegate, HelloWorldLayer, and IntroLayer

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that in Coco2d 2.0 rc1 it was as I described, but in Cocos2d 2.0 the RootViewController class was removed and replaced by having the CCDirector is a subclass of CC_VIEWCONTROLLER and on ios CC_VIEWCONTROLLER is defined to be UIViewController. The director does set the AppDelegate to be the ViewController delegate, so your method placement of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in the AppDelegate is correct.

Comment: Do you have a Cocos2d scene with Cocos2d content that you can run to see if that rotates properly to landscape? I am guessing that your issue has something to do with that you defined Main Menu View Controller using storyboard in landscape.

Comment: Before I implemented the MainMenu Scene and just ran the cocos2d game on startup, it was in the correct landscape orientation, but when I incorporated storyboard and the MainMenu Scene, the view is wrong as seen in the pictures.

Comment: The issue seems to be with integrating storyboard into Cocos2d in landscape mode. Might want to ask a new question that states that more clearly. I have not added storyboard to Cocos2d before, so just a guess, but did you create a custom view controller for Main Menu View Controller and add the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: to that view controller as well?

Comment: Here is a link to how I did it.  I answered my own question with how  I did it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550437/how-to-incorporate-storyboards-into-a-cocos2d-2-0-project

Comment: hi it's working for iphone but not ipad. Ive changed the method in the app delegate as well as xcode's info setting page.