# Cocos2d+Storyboards, how can I get a working project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, interface-builder, uistoryboard

**EDIT:**
Accept / Bounty goes to anyone who can tell me how to make a project that:

- Uses Cocos2d 2.x
- Has Storyboards
- Has ARC
- Bonus if you provide a download link to a template

**The previous question became a mess, and I've pretty much solved it myself. The Bounty is still up for grabs, if anyone wants to make a better version of my project.**

[HERE IS A WORKING, CLEAN, READY-TO-USE TEMPLATE FOR ANYONE TO USE, COMPLETE WITH ARC, COCOS2D 2.1, STORYBOARDS AND EVERYTHING](http://www.mediafire.com/?7dil7uolo5k1syr)

Tested in Xcode 4, 5, iOS 6, 7, only on iPhone but should work on iPad aswell.

I looked hard for this when I worked on making this, so I hope I do someone a favour with this. Credit goes to Tiny Tim Games and https://stackoverflow.com/a/11801085/1701411 for the custom files. I've slightly modified these files to work. Usage instructions for noobs is inside the project readme! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar project template.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/7dil7uolo5k1syr/Cocos2d+and+Storyboards+and+ARC+template.zip

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any code to support your question but from experience, you could try using `self.view.bounds` instead of `self.view.frame`?

**Update**

Create a property for your `CCGLView` in your view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic) CCGLView *glView;
```

Then create an instance of it as you already have, but saved to your property.

```
[self setGlView:[[CCGLView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
```

Then implement `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and update the frame of your `CCGLView` to match.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [[self glView] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
}
```

Comment: Code is the first thing you would've seen if you looked at the linked SO answer. I felt that it was unnecessary to paste code that I didn't create when its linked to the source explaining it. The problem is not logging the proper screen size, but that my project somehow thinks it is portrait. And for the record, it seems like the `CCViewController` uses `.bounds`

Comment: I did look at the question you linked but nowhere does it use either `view.frame` or `view.bounds` which is what I thought may be causing a problem.

Comment: in what context do you want me to use `view.frame`? Its used in "cocos2dViewController.m" in `CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bounds]` But the issue is still there when I log the size of the UIView without cocos2d, and even if the view was landscape, why is the top bar still there when I disabled it? I think there is some storyboard / xcode funnystuff going on somewhere. I also added a DL Link for the project in the question, feel free to have a look.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Xcode 5. It may be a bug in the developer preview. I don't use storyboards myself as from experience they've caused me nothing but pain.

Comment: I'll try to re-create it in XC4, check back in half n hour. Btw, what do you do instead of storyboards?

Comment: I just do it all programatically. Storyboards are a huge PITA. From your other question, I'd perhaps suggest calling your `CCGLView viewWithFrame:` in the `viewWillAppear` method and passing in `self.view.bounds` rather than `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bounds]`.

Comment: Re-created it in XC4, and did the .bounds thingy. (http://www.mediafire.com/?l0mcxawcacapm41) Now this opened the door for some more exciting bugs. It now displays properly placed in the view, but only on the second+ time I try to load the instance. The top bar still doesn't go away when I tell it to.

Comment: Your storyboard uses a `UINavigationController`. Unless you need to navigate away from your current view controller, get rid of this and you won't have to deal with trying to hide it. If you do need it, hide the navigation bar in your view controller with `[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setHidden:YES]` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I hate it and have no idea how to use it, but when I tried to ditch it I just got two truckloads of errors, so I figured that I should just let it do its thing. I just figured that every view connected to the navController inherits the behavior of it, so when I kill top bars in the navController, ever view does the same thing. The only error left now is why the cocos2d view is off (http://i.imgur.com/5CwcfVk.png) on the first launch. Any idea?

Comment: Not a clue, sorry. Again, it's probably usage of frame rather than bounds before the interface orientation has been updated. If you can set the frame of your `CCGLView`, try setting it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: I did your `self.view.bounds`. I did not understand what you said there, can you explain? :)

Comment: In your view controller, implement `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and call `self.glView.frame = self.view.bounds;` or the appropriate code for updating the frame of your `CCGLView`.

Comment: Tried, couldn't make it work. Sample code please? Sorry for being so bad.

Comment: Tried the updated answer, but I might have done it wrong somehow. When I did it in both cocos2dViewController and CCViewController, it just showed me the ./123456789 on the first launch. When I did it in just cocos2d... it blackscreeened, and when I did it in only CCView it had the old glitch on first launch and ./1-9 on second. Can you please make a project yourself and properly implement it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Cocoas2D. It sounds like you're missing something basic somewhere along the way. Perhaps start a new project and try debugging it as you go rather than trying to fix your current project.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. I'll try that. You're impressingly good if you don't even know cocos2d!

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with this issue. Here is how I created iOS project (with ARC and storyboards) that uses Cocos2d-iphone library.

1. create new XCode **Cocos2d iOS project** from template
2. create new XCode **iOS single view application project**
3. in Finder, find Cocos2d project folder created in step 1
4. Drag-and-drop libs folder from cocos2d project to single view application project in XCode (select "Copy files" option when prompted, and be sure to mark project target)

**In iOS single view application project:**

1. Go to `Build Phases -> Compile Sources` and select all files from ProjectName/libs/ folder
2. Double click on the right to add compiler flag
3. In Compiler Flag window write `-fno-objc-arc` to disable ARC for that files (cocos2d lib files are written with all necessary memory management code so we don't need ARC for them).
4. Go to Build Settings
   9.. In `Header Search Paths` add: `"libs/kazmath/include"` (go to project folder in Finder and double check path)
5. In `Other Linker Flags` add: `-lz -ObjC`
6. All that is left is to add necessary frameworks. Go to Build Phases and open Link Binary With Libraries
7. This libraries must be added (some may be already included):

   - AVFoundation.framework
   - AudioToolbox.framework
   - OpenAL.framework
   - QuartzCore.framework
   - OpenGLES.framework
   - UIKit.framework
   - Foundation.framework
   - CoreGraphics.framework
8. CMD+B to see if project can build

Here is sample project: [PROJECT TEMPLATE DOWNLOAD](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1mkpddcfszq6jt/Cocos2d_UIKIt_Demo.zip).